# Jetty - large messages filtering

Tags: jetty

Hi I want to refuse incoming requests with too large body or header in my Jetty.I suppose that I have to set some filter, but I haven't found any solution.  Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to build a Servlet `Filter` or Jetty `Handler` that pays attention to the request's `Content-Length` header and then rejects (responds with an http error status code) the request.

As for the header size limit, that's controlled by the [`HttpConfiguration.setRequestHeaderSize(int)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.html#setRequestHeaderSize(int))

However, there are a class of requests, that uses Chunked `Transfer-Encoding`, with these kinds of requests, there is no `Content-Length` and you will just have to reject the request when reading from the [`HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()) after it hits a certain size.

There is also the complication of Mime multi-part request body content and how you determine the request content is too large.

One other note, unfortunately, due to how HTTP connection handling must be performed, even if a client sends you too large of a request body content, the server still has to read that entire body content and throw it away.  This is the half-closed scenario found in the spec, its up to the client to see the early rejected http response and close/terminate the connection.